# Android - connect to known hidden Wi-Fi network

Tags: android, wifi, hidden

I need to connect to hidden Wi-Fi network programmatically. 
I know it's SSID, security type and password. 
For some reason I can't connect it.

I can connect to the same network if it's not hidden.

Here's my code:

```java
// configure the network
private void saveWPANetwork(WiFiNetwork network){     
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration(); 
    conf.SSID =network.getSSID(); 
    conf.hiddenSSID = true; 
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED; 
    conf.preSharedKey =network.getPassword(); 
    conf.priority = 9999; 
    wifi.addNetwork(conf); 
    wifi.saveConfiguration(); 
}

// connect it
protected boolean connectToVaildNetwork() { 

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
    if(list == null) 
        return false; 

    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) { 
        for (WiFiNetwork network : config.wiFiNetworksDetails) { 
            if(network.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase(i.SSID)){ 
                wifi.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true); 
                return wifi.reconnect(); /// STRANGE BUT IT ALWAYS RETURNS TRUE, EVEN IF DEVICE IS NOT CONNECTED TO THE  HIDDEN NETWORK! 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer maybe late but I still post it in case of someone need.
Android 4.4.2 tested. Notes that hidden networks take longer time to connect (for my test it was around 10-15s)

wifi.reconnect() == true means that your command has been requested successfully, it does not mean that wifi is connected.

```
public void setWifiConfig(String ssid, String sharedKey) {
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain ssid in quotes

    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + sharedKey + "\"";

    conf.hiddenSSID = true;
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {

            wifiManager.disconnect();

            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);

            wifiManager.reconnect();

            wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, your answer works for me. FYI, my device is based on Android 5.1.1

Comment: I have tried on android 7 and could not make it work, any idea if it works on the new API?

Comment: can u try  `conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);`

Comment: No Success: i just printed the value of i, and got this. what could be the reason?
- DSBLE ID: 66 SSID: "myHiddenSSID" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 783
numAssociation 11
validatedInternetAccess
KeyMgmt: WPA_PSK Protocols: WPA RSN
AuthAlgorithms: OPEN
PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
GroupCiphers: TKIP CCMP
PSK: *
Enterprise config:
password *
engine 0
client_cert NULL
anonymous_identity NULL
ca_cert2 NULL
identity *
domain_suffix_match NULL
phase2 NULL
altsubject_match NULL
subject_match NULL
ca_cert NULL
key_id NULL
engine_id NULL
eap NULL

Comment: You need to update some lines of the code to be like this:
`int networkId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(conf);`
and in the if statement it should look like this:
`if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"") && networkId == i.networkId)`

you need to check the networkId in case the user already has a saved network with the same name of the hidden network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me to understand how it worked in Android before version 10.
To make it work in Android 10+, WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder class should be used with setIsHiddenSsid method.