# Connecting to a Hidden Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-wifi

I am creating an Android application which should connect to a known available Hidden Wi-Fi network.

Which is the proper approach to handle this scenario ?

I have implemented trying to connect to a hidden wifi network. I tried on android devices with OS versions 6.0, 7.0, 7.1.1, 8.0 But couldn't achieve success.

```
fun initiateWifiConnectivity(mContext: Context, sSID: String, password: String) {
        mWifiManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

        if (!mWifiManager!!.isWifiEnabled) {
            mWifiManager!!.isWifiEnabled = true
        }

        mWifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
        mWifiConfiguration!!.SSID = convertToQuotedString(sSID)
        mWifiConfiguration!!.preSharedKey = password
        mWifiConfiguration!!.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
        mWifiConfiguration!!.hiddenSSID = true

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedAuthAlgorithms.
     set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.LEAP)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedGroupCiphers.
     set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedGroupCiphers.
     set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedGroupCiphers.
     set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedKeyManagement.
     set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedKeyManagement.
     set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedKeyManagement.
     set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedPairwiseCiphers.
     set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedPairwiseCiphers.
     set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedPairwiseCiphers.
     set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.NONE)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedProtocols.
     set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)

     mWifiConfiguration!!.allowedProtocols.
     set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)

        mWifiManager!!.addNetwork(mWifiConfiguration!!)

         Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
             val list = mWifiManager!!.configuredNetworks
             for (i in list) {
                 if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID == 
convertToQuotedString(sSID)) {

                     mWifiManager!!.disconnect()
                     mWifiManager!!.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true)
                     mWifiManager!!.reconnect()

                     break
                 }
             }
         }, 15000)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36405150/5773037

Comment: @NikunjParadva I already tried this but didn't get connected. Will check

Comment: @AhamedMujeeb did u managed to find the solution? can you please share?

Comment: @AnantShah No solution yet. Requirement exists. Temporally made the wifi a Visible wifi from hardware level to continue work.

Answer (score 1):

I connected a hidden WIFI network in Android Studio with a divice Android 7.0. Put the conf.hiddenSSID = true; of the object WifiConfiguration, the configuration to connect a network is similar to a notable network.

```
public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WifiManager wifiManager; // Here is defined the instance

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    Log.d("Aut", Net + " : " + Pw);
    conf.SSID = "\"" + Net + "\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + Pw + "\"";
    conf.hiddenSSID = true; // Put this line to hidden SSID
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP); 
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP); 
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

    // Connect Network

    this.wifiManager =(WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    assert wifiManager != null;

    int netId = this.wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);    
    WifiInfo wifi_inf = this.wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    this.wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifi_inf.getNetworkId());
    this.wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    this.wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me to understand how it worked in Android before version 10.
To make it work in Android 10+, WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder class should be used with setIsHiddenSsid method.